# Check if a list contained by another without reusing occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need help so that if user input "goood" it should print not from the above letters. if user input god is should be valid word

```
valid  = ['g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'c']
print(valid)
word = input('please make a word using above letters: ')
if any(letter in word for letter in valid):
    print('yes valid word')
else:
    print('not from the above letter')
```

Comment: any permutation of `valid` is acceptable?

Comment: Why should it print `not from the above letter` for `goood` and `valid word` for `god`?

Comment: Your question is ill-defined because you don't actually give the wanted specs, just the result on one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valid  = ['g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'c']

def is_valid(test_word,alphabet):
    valid_copy = alphabet[:]
    for letter in test_word:
        try: 
           valid_copy.remove(letter)
        except ValueError:
           # there are no more of this letter in the word
           print("Invalid Word")
           return False
    print("Valid Word")
    return True
   

is_valid("good",valid)
is_valid("food",valid)
```

if you need to rapidly test many words there are likely(definitely) better ways to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can make a counter containing letter count then use that to compare if the count of letters in the valid list is greater than or equal to the occurences of the letter in the word

```
from collections import Counter
v_count = Counter(valid)
all(v_count[letter] >= word.count(letter) for letter in set(word))
```

Comment: Ninja'd, good answer

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `Counter`s is to `subtract` the current word from the counter, then check in the counter if any element's count is negative (or, the opposite, check if all elements' counts are positive).

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> valid = ['g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'c']
>>> word = "god"
>>> counter = Counter(valid)
>>> counter.subtract(word)
>>> all(count >= 0 for count in counter.values())
True
```

Pay attention: `subtract` [changes the counter in-place](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract), so you need to recreate it if you need to perform this check with other words.

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use following:

```
valid  = ['g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'c']
print(valid)
len_valid = len(valid)
word = input('please make a word using above letters: ')

def sample(valid):
    if (len_valid - len(valid)) == len(word): 
        print('yes valid word')
    else:
        print('not from the above letter')

for w in word:
    if w not in valid:
        break
    elif w in valid:
        valid.remove(w)
        #print(w)

if len(word) != 0:
    sample(valid)
```

Comment: May I ask why downvote? Do you think it is not resolving the problem?

Comment: Because it is uselessly convoluted (as soon as you don't have `w in valid`, you could stop processing the word, instead you check indirectly — via the length of `valid` — how many times this condition was met, and ensure it was as many times as there were iterations) and inefficient (even wrt the other answers which are already wasteful). It does solve the problem, in the sense that in the end you will get the right result, but it's not a canonical answer: `Counter` is in the standard library, and solves this exact issue, so not using it should not be considered an idiomatic answer.

Comment: If the case is to not break the loop when 'w' not in 'valid'. Yes, you are correct. So that I have improved my answer accordingly. In some cases, there won't be possible to install some packages into host. I think that, in such cases, it is important to have a code which runs without installing any package. (like 'Counter')